# Is there a way to link 2D view and 3D view in a layout - QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d, atlas

Is there a way to link 2D view and 3D views in a layout using QGIS? In the 3D view I selected the option of having the view move with the 2D view. However, when I get to the layout and run the atlas (that is one the 2D view map), the 3D view does not change. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Using `QGIS` 3.28.13, when you open the 3D view window, go to Options (the small wrench thing) the select `3D camera follows 2D map view`. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHnNpH0Dkh8&ab_channel=GISCoordinated) youtube video shows step by step how to do it as well.

[image: option to link 2D and 3D views]